# how to send packet from another peer using teredo tunnel?

Tags: c#, windows-7, network-programming, ipv6, p2p

I'm trying to build a UDP-based p2p c# application using [teredo interface](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457011.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  , and I managed to enable this interface on my windows 7 OS using the command :

```
netsh interface teredo>set state client teredo.remlab.net 60 23456
```

and after activating it the `netsh interface teredo>show state` command printed :

```
Type                    : client
Server Name             : teredo.remlab.net
Client Refresh Interval : 60 seconds
Client Port             : 23456
State                   : qualified
Client Type             : teredo client
Network                 : unmanaged
NAT                     : symmetric (port)
NAT Special Behaviour   : UPNP: Yes, PortPreserving: No
Local Mapping           : 192.168.8.100:23456
External NAT Mapping    : 188.247.74.161:37457
```

and pinging google ipv6-based host using the command `ping -t -6 www.google.com` printed :

```
Pinging www.google.com [2a00:1450:4007:807::2004] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4007:807::2004: time=123ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4007:807::2004: time=121ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4007:807::2004: time=127ms
```

now my question is : is this enough to say that I'm accessible from outside my Lan using teredo ? and if so .. what my external End points that will let other peers to access me ?

this is my c# code for listen to the teredo interface (correct me if something wrong with it) :

```
UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(23456, AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);
Client.AllowNatTraversal(true);
Client.Client.SetIPProtectionLevel(IPProtectionLevel.Unrestricted);
int counter = 0;
while(true)
{
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,0);
    Byte[] receiveBytes = Client.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
    string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + returnData.ToString() + " -" + counter);
    counter++;
}
```

and this is my code for send a message from a peer to my pc (here I got confused) :

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);
byte[] Message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello my fiend");
//not sure what to put here .. but the following works and print results in the listener console from within my LAN 
client.Send(Message, Message.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("2001:0:53aa:64c:3057:6dae:4308:b55e"), 23456));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: You probably want to allow nat traversal and set `IPProtectionLevel.Unrestricted` on both ends for a p2p client.

Comment: @the8472 thank you for this valuable info ...but are those Endpoints that I used in client correct ? I mean if wanted to send a message from client to the listener ( from outside LAN ) should I use those Endpoints or something else ?